# Induction for f$(n+2)=f(n+1)+6f(n)$ and its property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, relations

i'm having real hard time with this:

f:N->N is defined in recursion as following: f(0)=0, f(1)=10, and for ever $n \in N$ $f(n+2)=f(n+1)+6f(n)$.

a) prove by induction (only induction) that $f(n)=2*3^n+(-2)^{n+1}$

b)is f surjective?

what i tried to do:

a)i don't even know how to prove it by induction, so i tried to use common sense. since it's known that $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=10$, then if we input n=0, we get $f(0+2)=f(0+1)+6f(n) -> f(2)=10$. so we'll check for n=1, and get $f(1)=2*3+4=10$ which is valid. now we'll assume that f(n) is true and used it as the basis of induction and try to prove it for the next element, i.e f(n+1): $f(n+1)=2*3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+2}=2*3^n*3+(-2)*(-2)^{n+1}$, now since we assumed $f(n)=2*3^n+(-2)^{n+1}$ is true, we'll substract $f(n+1)-f(n)$ to get f(1) and we get it's equal to 10. so by using the induction principle we've proven it's true for every $n \in N$

b)after showing f(n) is true, we can use it's properties to assert that for every $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in x$ there's f(x)=y, to claim it's surjective, while considering it's definition, i.e: f:N->N. if we look at f, we see that it is always natural, since $3^n \geq (-2)^{n+1}$, since if $(-2)^{n+1}$ is negative then 3^n will always make it bigger than 0, and if it's positive there would always be a representation of it in N (i don't know how to prove it correctly).

please help me write it correctly. i've written everything i've done and tried to elabroate as much as i can

Comment: How can $f$ be surjective, if all $f(n)$ are even integers?

Comment: You should replace "$f(n)$ is true" by "$P(n)$ is true", where $P(n)$ denotes the property : "f(n) = 2\times3^n+(-2)^{n+1}".

Comment: ohhh, i was looking at the wrong direction. thank you very much.

could you please comment on the way i've done the induction please?

can you explain why? so i'll also learn and not just do please?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the function expression to be right for $n$ and $n+1$.

$$f(n)=2\cdot3^n+(-2)^{n+1},\\
f(n+1)=2\cdot3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+2}.$$

Then by the recurrence relation,

$$f(n+2)=f(n+1)+6f(n)=2\cdot3^{n+1}+(-2)^{n+2}+6(2\cdot3^n+(-2)^{n+1})\\
=18\cdot3^n-8\cdot2^n=2\cdot3^{n+2}+(-2)^{n+3}$$ and the function expression is right for $n+2$.

And for the base case,

$$f(2)=2\cdot3^2+(-2)^3=10=f(1)+f(0).$$

---

The function is clearly growing, and there is certainly no $n$ such that

$$f(n)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the recurrence to show that as soon as you have two consecutive positive terms the sequence is increasing. Then compute some values and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- On (a), you have shown the hypothesis formula is true for $n=1$.  In this case you need to start by showing it is true for consecutive numbers, so show it is also true for $n=0$ or $n=2$ at the start. Then, assuming it is true for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$, you need to show it is true for $n=k+2$. Combined this provides the proof by induction.
- On (b), the sequence starts $0,10,10,70,130,550,1330,\ldots$. Does this look surjective, i.e. giving every natural number?